# Linear transformation of eigenspace is subset of eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, function-and-relation-composition

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and let $L$, $M$ be two linear transformations from $V$ to itself.

a. Show that the subset $W= {x ∈ V : L(x) = M(x)}$ is a subspace of $V$

b. Suppose that $L\circ M = M\circ L$. Show that $L(E_{\lambda}(M))\subseteq E_{\lambda}(M)$ for all $\lambda\in F$.

I'm stuck on b but have included a in case it helps. At the moment i'm confused - I know $E_{\lambda}(M)$ is a subspace of $V$, and that $L(E_{\lambda}(M))=M(E_{\lambda}(L))$, but i'm not sure how this helps.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hint: For every $v$, $LMv = MLv$. Now choose $v$ to be an eigenvector of $M$.

Comment: Ok so by the hint **LM**v= **ML**v= **λL**v, so we have Lv as our eigenvector of M which is a subset of Eλ(M)?

Comment: Looks good so far...

Comment: Where do I go from here? Do I need to show the first part of the definition for an eigenspace, that is $$x\in V$$ so I need to show $$Lx\in V$$?